# Programming the OS to execute a file

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I' never done something like that and I don't even know if it is possible.
In my website, I have a .php file that reads a .json file and update the database according to this .json.

I want the server to execute this .php script every hour(or something like that).

Is that possible? How do I do that? 
If it is impossible, why?

Comment: You should read more about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Cron! https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely possible, assuming you have `php5-cli` installed.

Just type `crontab -e`, and then add the following line. This will cause `php` to be run with your script as an argument every hour, on the hour.

```
0 * * * * php path/to/MyScript.php
```

Alternately, you can put `#!/usr/bin/php` at the top of your script, do `chmod +x MyScript.php` and replace the line above the following.

```
0 * * * * path/to/MyScript.php
```